Программное увеличение VRAM на дискретной видеопамяти
Появилась необходимость в дополнительной видеопамяти для графики и не только на дискретной видеокарте на ноутбуке MSI GF63 Thin. Стоит видеокарта rtx 3050 4гб и 16гб озу в двухканале.
Находил в интернете прогу от Nvidia, которая на видеокартах с менее 3гб VRAM программно увеличивает видеопамять, но говорят не подходит для карт с большим объемом.
Есть ли другие способы и программы для увеличение VRAM?
